# willEndFullScreenPresentationWithAnimationCoordinator not fire when video is closed

Tags: ios, xamarin, video-streaming, mvvmcross, nsobject

Hi I have an application that is based on Xamarin MvvmCross framework that uses the AVPlayerItem of NSOject library from iOS. Whenever the video playback is closed, the quiz should pop up due to an observer notifying when Full Screen Presentation With Animation Coordinator Ended. Most frequently, the function WillEndFullScreenPresentation is fired. But sometimes when I swipe too fast or close during pause, this function is fired before the video playback was called. How do I prevent this from happening?

```
private void SetVideoPlayer(VideoAsset video)
        {

            var player = new AVPlayer(new NSUrl(video.VideoUrl));
            ViewModel.WatchedVideoAssetCommand.Execute(video);
            aVPlayerViewController = new AVPlayerViewController();
            aVPlayerViewController.Player = player;
            aVPlayerViewController.Delegate = this;
            this.PresentViewController(aVPlayerViewController, true, () =>
            {
                aVPlayerViewController.Player?.Play();
            });
            //NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: Selector(("playerDidFinishPlaying:")),
            //name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: fourVideoPlayer.player.currentItem)
            
            NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(AVPlayerItem.DidPlayToEndTimeNotification, (notify) => {
                notify.Dispose();
                aVPlayerViewController.DismissModalViewController(true);
            });

            NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(AVPlayerItem.ItemFailedToPlayToEndTimeNotification, (notify) =>
            {
                notify.Dispose();
                aVPlayerViewController.DismissModalViewController(true);
            });
        }

        [Export("playerViewController:willEndFullScreenPresentationWithAnimationCoordinator:")]
        public void WillEndFullScreenPresentation(AVPlayerViewController playerViewController, IUIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator coordinator)
        {
            ViewModel.StartQuizForVideoAssetCommand.Execute(ViewModel.PlayingAsset);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a **[AVPlayerTimeControlStatus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/avfoundation.avplayertimecontrolstatus?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12)** property of **AVPlayer**:

[image]

> But sometimes when I swipe too fast or close during pause, this function is fired before the video playback was called.

You could check this status in `WillEndFullScreenPresentation` method to determine whehter need to exit full screen.

Sample code as follows:

```
[Export("playerViewController:willEndFullScreenPresentationWithAnimationCoordinator:")]
public void WillEndFullScreenPresentation(AVPlayerViewController playerViewController, IUIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator coordinator)
{
    if (aVPlayerViewController.Player.TimeControlStatus != AVFoundation.AVPlayerTimeControlStatus.Paused || aVPlayerViewController.Player.TimeControlStatus != AVFoundation.AVPlayerTimeControlStatus.WaitingToPlayAtSpecifiedRate)
    {
        ViewModel.StartQuizForVideoAssetCommand.Execute(ViewModel.PlayingAsset);
    }

}
```

Comment: Applied this fix, didn't notice much difference but the bug is rarely produced. In fact it is very hard to reproduce this bug.

Comment: @TPHo Okey, If the reply is helpful, please do not forget to accept it as answer( click the ✔ in the upper left corner of this answer) and vote it up, it will help others who have similar issue.